# Generic error handler generates error message duplicates

Tags: rebus

Im having problems with duplicate error messages using rebus with autofac.
Im trying to use a generic error handling setup with second level retries. The setup is as follow:

Error handler:

```
public class ErrorHandler<T>: IHandleMessages<IFailed<T>>
{
    public ErrorHandler()
    {

    }

    public async Task Handle(IFailed<T> message)
    {

    }
}
```

Registration:

```
var failedtyp = typeof(IHandleMessages<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IFailed<>));
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ErrorHandler<>)).As(failedtyp).SingleInstance();
```

The purpose is to use the same handler for all types of messages.
Setting up the error handler for a specific type of error message works as expected.

EDIT: Sample console application with Rebus, Rebus.SqlServer and Rebus.Autofac

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autofac;
using Rebus.Bus;
using Rebus.Config;
using Rebus.Handlers;
using Rebus.Retry.Simple;

namespace RebusDuplicateTest
{
class Program
{
    private static IContainer container;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cb = new ContainerBuilder();

        cb.RegisterRebus((conf,cc) => conf.Options(b => b
            .SimpleRetryStrategy(maxDeliveryAttempts:1,secondLevelRetriesEnabled: true))
            .Transport(c => c.UseSqlServer("Database=rebus_test_db;Server=(local);App=Hubert-Utv;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI","queuename"))
            .Logging(c => c.None())
            .Options(o => o.SetMaxParallelism(1)));
        cb.RegisterHandler<Handler>();

        var failedtyp = typeof(IHandleMessages<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IFailed<>));
        cb.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ErrorHandler<>)).As(failedtyp).SingleInstance();

        container = cb.Build();

        var bus = container.Resolve<IBus>();
        bus.SendLocal(new TestClass());

        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)).Wait();
    }
}

public class Handler : IHandleMessages<TestClass>
{
    static int counter = 1;

    public async Task Handle(TestClass message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Handler called {counter++} times");
        throw new Exception("Throws!");
    }
}

public class ErrorHandler<T> : IHandleMessages<IFailed<T>>
{
    private readonly IBus bus;

    private static int counter = 1;

    public ErrorHandler(IBus bus)
    {
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public async Task Handle(IFailed<T> message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error handler called {counter++} times");
        await bus.DeferLocal(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),message.Message);
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
}
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe describe in a little bit more detail in what this doesn't work...?

Comment: @mookid8000 Sorry. The problem is that i get the error event handler called twice when the ioc container is setup like in the description, with a generic registration. When i have tested with an error event handler for a specific message type implementation i get the expected behavior. I get the feeling rebus resolves two instances of the error event handler but i might be wrong :)

Comment: @mookid8000 I added a sample console application showing my problem. Maybe im doing something wrong but the registrations seem right to me. Forgot to mention i am using rebus.sqlserver.